# How to add authors page, authors profile and pics on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a plugin that would add the folloiwng on our blog site built on Wordpess slef hosted:

1. Authors' name to appear on every blog (below title where currentlly date and tags appear)
2. Authors page being added to our blog site
3. On authors page display authors' profile including bio, website, social network profile buttons and published posts.

So it would be more like how it is set-up at Mashable: http://mashable.com/author/pete-cashmore/.

Is there a plugin or plugins I could use to achieve these?

Thank for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<?php the_author(); ?>`

like
`<p>This post was written by <?php the_author(); ?></p>`

and use custom permalinks

like `/%postname%/`
so you will get the author page

`domain.com/author/name`

Comment: Thanks but your suggestion doesnt guide me through where to add/modify. I was hoping there was a plugin that could do all of these.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to add authors pages, profiles, and pics on WordPress.

**1. Use a plugin:**
There are a number of plugins that can help you add authors pages, profiles, and pics to your WordPress site.

**2. Use custom code:**
If you are comfortable with coding, you can also add authors pages, profiles, and pics to your WordPress site using custom code.

**3. Use a theme:**
Some WordPress themes include built-in support for authors pages, profiles, and pics. If you are using a theme that supports this feature, you can usually find the settings in the theme's options panel.